# how to reload tableview of another uiviewcontroller in current viewcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, viewcontroller

Please help me out. I am very sorry if it is duplicate but i didn't get required answer that is why i am asking again.
I want to reload table of anotherview in my first view.

Thanks in adavance.

Comment: Have you tried to reload the tableView in ViewwillAppear. [self.tableView reloadData];

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the first viewcontroller.m, I put this in the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handle_data) name:@"reload_data" object:nil];

    -(void)handle_data {
        [yourtableview reloaddata];
    }
```

In the second viewcontroller.m:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reload_data" object:self];
```

Comment: Works well..!! (Y)

Answer (score 3):

1. Create property for `UITableview` with `nonatomic` and `retain`.. (view controller 1)
2. in View Controller 2 create object of viewcontroller 1.
3. now with help of viewcontroller 1 object you can access it.

**Example**:

In ViewController2 .m file:

```
ViewController1 *objV1 = [ViewController1 alloc]initWithNibName....];   

[objV1.yourTableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it in below way:

Suppose you have 2 view controller.

- ViewController1
- ViewController2

And you have `UITableView` object `tblTable` in `ViewController2`.

in `ViewController2.h` file:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UITableView *tblTable;
```

in `ViewController2.m` file:

```
@synthesize tblTable;
```

Now in in `ViewController1.m` file:

```
ViewController1 *objV1 = [ViewController1 alloc]initWithNibName....];

[objV1.tblTable reloadData];
```

I hope it will be helpful to you.

Let me know in case of any difficulty.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and I was using storyboard this is how I fixed it. Suppose u want to reload the table which is in ViewController2 from a function in ViewController1. Do the following:

```
 #import "ViewController2.h"
```

Now put this code in the function or any button action under which u want to reload

```
ViewController2 *ob= (ViewController2*)[self.navigationController topViewController];
    [ob.viewController2Table reloadData];
```