# My reloaddata call in not calling the delegate methods in UItableviewcontroller?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an application in which i am using a sidemenu controller like a facebook app.its basically a `UITableViewController`.when i am using `[self.tableView reloaddata]` in the view will appear methode for the first time its working fine.Because of some requirement i need to reload this table view from another view controller.so i did this:

```
 SideMenuViewController *second = [[SideMenuViewController alloc]init];
 [second viewWillappear:YES]
```

where i am reloading the data.But when i am doing this the reloaddata is not calling the cellforindexmethode of the tableviewcontroller But it is calling the numberOfRowsInSection methode.Can anybody help me in finding where i am going wrong.

Comment: You creates a new instance of the SideMEnuViewController and call viewWillAppear on it?

Comment: @angry_developer: how did you show another view controller from SideMenuViewController ?

Comment: when i am coming back to a view controller i need toshow this view controller as menu.at that time i need to reload that data,thats why i am ding this.but it is calling only numberOfRowsInSection not the other methodes

Comment: @angry_developer: if you click on the tableView you are displaying a view. When you return from that view you need to reload table, am i correct ?

Comment: @MidhunMP when i am clicking on a button ,which takes me back to a view controller,there itself i need to show this tableview controller as the menu.as a half part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a notification to to this.

In the SideMenuViewController viewDidLoad method you add a this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(reloadTable)
                                             name:@"SideMenuShouldRefreshDataNotification"
                                           object:nil];
```

The reloadTable method looks like this:

```
-(void)reloadTable {
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
  [self.tableView reloadData];
});
}
```

When you want to refresh the table you just post this notification from anywhere you want in your app.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:[NSNotification notificationWithName:@"SideMenuShouldRefreshDataNotification" object:nil]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this and check this below:

```
[[self yourtableviewname] reloadData];
```

Comment: read the question its a tableviewcontroller.not an iboutlet view

Comment: in tableviewname add uitableviewcontroller object name

Answer (score 0):

If you creates a new instance and call a method on it, it won't cause that your old one will be refreshed. Call `refreshData` on your existing `TableView` instance, instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Reload using a protocol delegate.
Another view controller may not be able to call viewWillAppear in the manner you are using.
REload the tableview by writing a delegate that would return to the controller which has tableview in it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: it will be great if u can give a detailed answer

Comment: Tried this? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130314/how-to-reload-tableview-of-another-uiviewcontroller-in-current-viewcontroller)

Comment: ,,i have a tableviewcontroller,not the uiviewcontrollr with tableview

Comment: SideMenuViewController *second = [[SideMenuViewController alloc]init];[second.tableViewController reloadData]

Answer (score 0):

This code never reload your tableView:

```
SideMenuViewController *second = [[SideMenuViewController alloc]init];
[second viewWillappear:YES]
```

Because here you are creating a new instance of your `SideMenuViewController` class. If you call the reloadData it won't refresh the previous tableView instance.

And calling the `viewWillappear` delegate method forcibly is a bad habit.

**Solution:**

Declare an instance of `SideMenuViewController` in the @interface of your viewController and write propert for that.
When you go to that view set the `SideViewController` instance.
And when the user press the back button call:

```
[sideViewControllerObject.tablView reloadData];
```

Comment: i did it,but nothing happend,i need to alloc it?

Comment: no. did you set that instance variable ? I think that is nil.

Comment: means?i added the instance variuble and with that i done th eprocess.how to set it?sidemenu=[[SideMenuViewController alloc]init];

Comment: know when you go to the viewController set it like: viewControllerObj.sideViewControllerObject = self.currentsideViewControllerObject;